# How to update rows in spark dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to update some rows of dataframe ,below is my code.

```
dfs_ids1 = dfs_ids1.withColumn("arrival_dt", F.when(F.col("arrival_dt")=='1960-01-01', lit(None)) )
```

Basically, I want to update all the rows where **arrival_dt**  is **1960-01-01** with ***null*** and leave rest of the rows *unchanged*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the `filter` and `when` functions.

If you want to fetch rows only without caring about others , try this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

dfs_ids1 = dfs_ids1.filter(col("arrival_dt='1960-01-01'"))
```

If you want to update remaining with custom value or other columns.

```
dfs_ids1=dfs_ids1.withColumn("arrival_dt",when(col("arrival_dt")=="1960-01-01",col("arrival_dt")).otherwise(lit(None))) 

//Or

dfs_ids1=dfs_ids1.withColumn("arrival_dt",when(col("arrival_dt")=="1960-01-01",col("arrival_dt")))

//Sample example

//Input df

+------+-------+-----+
|  name|   city|state|
+------+-------+-----+
| manoj|gwalior|   mp|
| kumar|  delhi|delhi|
|dhakad|chennai|   tn|
+------+-------+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
opOneDf=df.withColumn("name",when(col("city")=="delhi",col("city")).otherwise(lit(None)))
opOneDf.show()

//Sample output

+-----+-------+-----+
| name|   city|state|
+-----+-------+-----+
| null|gwalior|   mp|
|delhi|  delhi|delhi|
| null|chennai|   tn|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Not working. Its not getting updated. 
I have udpated the code like below   
opOneDf=dfs_ids1.withColumn("arrival_dt",when(col("arrival_dt")=="1960-01-01",lit(None)).otherwise(col("arrival_dt")))

Comment: Can you please check your syntax?

Comment: Actually above code itself works,  had to rerun from top again. 
opOneDf=dfs_ids1.withColumn("departure_dt",when(col("departure_dt")=="1960-01-01",lit(None)).otherwise(col("departure_dt"))) .   

Lesson .otherwise is must, itseems